# How to find out in a shellscript if upgrades are available after an apt-get update

Tags: linux, debian, apt

I have a script that executes apt-get update on several servers and I have to find out whether there are upgrades available or not in order to schedule apt-get upgrades etc...

Looking at the docs I don't see how I could do this task.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apt-get -s dist-upgrade` and parse it's output. `-s` means simulation: no real actions will be done

Answer (score 0):

On one of my Ubuntu servers I use a program called `unattended-upgrades`. It sends me an email every night with a list of available updates.